# Objects don't move correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am currently programming a game where you have to dodge obstacles and reach the goal. There are a number of obstacles, based on the difficulty the player chose, which are moving in a straight line, in a random angle. If they reach the borders of the screen, they respawn at a random spawn point (there are three, also created random). The spawn points should remain stationary while you play a round and be recreated at different places when you start the next round.

If I now start the game, the spawn points move along with the obstacles which group and use a combined moving vector when spawning at the same spawn point.

I'll now list the classes that are important to indentify my problem:

1. The GamePanel (most of the game happens here):

   ```
   public class GamePanel extends JPanel
   {
   private JFrame fenster; //Frame for the game
   private final Dimension prefSize=new Dimension(1180, 780);  //preferred dimension
   private boolean gameOver=false,roundWin=false;  //booleans for round win and game over
   private Timer t;    //Timer
   private int c=0,p=0;    //counter and points
   private int[][] max;    //highscore Array
   private Player player=null; //playable game object
   private Goal goal=null; //the goal to end the round and earn points
   private int schwer=2;   //difficulty
   private Obstacle[] obstacles;   //obstacles to avoid
   private Spawn spawn0,spawn1,spawn2; //spawn points 1,2 and 3
   private Coordinate cSpawn0,cSpawn1,cSpawn2; //coordinates for the spawn points

   public GamePanel()
   {
       fenster = new JFrame();
       fenster.setTitle("Faster Course");
       fenster.setLocation(50,50);
       fenster.setResizable(false);
       fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       fenster.setVisible(true);
       fenster.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
       fenster.setSize(prefSize.width,prefSize.height);
       //fenster is specified

       JMenuBar Menü = new JMenuBar();
       JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
       JMenu game = new JMenu("Game");
       JMenu pref = new JMenu("Preferences");
       fenster.setJMenuBar(Menü);

       Menü.add(file);
       Menü.add(game);
       Menü.add(pref);
       //Menu for fenster is 'made'

       JMenuItem quit = new JMenuItem("Close");
       file.add(quit);
       quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               System.exit(0);     //if this button is clicked, the game exits
           }
       });

       JMenuItem diff = new JMenuItem("Difficulty");
       pref.add(diff);
       diff.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               JFrame Schwierigkeit = new JFrame();
               Schwierigkeit.setLayout(null);
               Schwierigkeit.setTitle("Difficulty");
               Schwierigkeit.setLocation(200,200);
               Schwierigkeit.setVisible(true);
               Schwierigkeit.setSize(30,275);
               Schwierigkeit.setResizable(false);                  

               JButton kLeicht=new JButton("Easy");
               kLeicht.setBounds(20,10,90,25);
               JButton kNormal=new JButton("Normal");
               kNormal.setBounds(20,50,90,25);
               JButton kSchwer=new JButton("Hard");
               kSchwer.setBounds(20,90,90,25);
               JButton kProfi=new JButton("Pro");
               kProfi.setBounds(20,130,90,25);
               JButton kAlbtraum=new JButton("Nightmare");
               kAlbtraum.setBounds(20,170,90,25);
               JButton kQual=new JButton("Torture");
               kQual.setBounds(20,210,90,25);

               Schwierigkeit.add(kLeicht);
               kLeicht.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                       Schwierigkeit.dispose();
                       changeDiff(1);                      
                   }
               });
               Schwierigkeit.add(kNormal);
               kNormal.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                       Schwierigkeit.dispose();
                       changeDiff(2);
                   }
               });
               Schwierigkeit.add(kSchwer);
               kSchwer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                       Schwierigkeit.dispose();
                       changeDiff(3);
                   }
               });
               Schwierigkeit.add(kProfi);
               kProfi.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                       Schwierigkeit.dispose();
                       changeDiff(4);
                   }
               });
               Schwierigkeit.add(kAlbtraum);
               kAlbtraum.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                       Schwierigkeit.dispose();
                       changeDiff(5);
                   }
               });
               Schwierigkeit.add(kQual);
               kQual.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
               {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                   {
                       Schwierigkeit.dispose();
                       changeDiff(6);
                   }
               });
           }               
       }); //if difficulty is clicked, a window to choose the difficulty is    opened
           //if a difficulty is chosen, the difficulty may be changed
       JMenuItem pause=new JMenuItem("Pause");
       game.add(pause);
       JMenuItem resume=new JMenuItem("Resume");
       game.add(resume);
       pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               pause.setEnabled(false);
               resume.setEnabled(true);            //if pause is clicked, the game is paused and pause 
               pauseGame();                        //cannot be clicked anymore but resume now can be
           }
       });
       resume.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               pause.setEnabled(true);
               resume.setEnabled(false);           //if resume is clicked,    the game continues and resume
               resumeGame();                       //cannot be clicked anymore but pause now can be
           }
       });

       max=new int[5][3];
       //highscores: 5 scores with each points[x][0], rounds[x][1] and difficulty[x][2]

       fenster.add(this);
       fenster.setVisible(true);   //now all is placed onto the JFrame
       initGame(); //all objects are initialized
       startGame();    //the game starts
   }

   public boolean isGameOver()
   {
       return gameOver;
   }

   public void setGameOver(boolean gameOver)
   {
       this.gameOver=gameOver;
   }

   public boolean isRoundWin()
   {
       return roundWin;
   }

   public void setRoundWin(boolean roundWin)
   {
       this.roundWin=roundWin;
   }

   public String schwerMax(int i)  //to return the words for the difficulty    numbers
   {
       if(i==1)
       {
           return "Easy";
       }
       else if(i==2)
       {
           return "Normal";
       }
       else if(i==3)
       {
           return "Hard";
       }
       else if(i==4)
       {
           return "Pro";
       }
       else if(i==5)
       {
           return "Nightmare";
       }
       else if(i==6)
       {
           return "Torture";
       }
       return "-";
   }

   private void initGame ()
   {
       createGameObjects();

       fenster.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() //controls and hotkeys
       {
           @Override
           public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
           {
               switch(e.getKeyCode())
               {
                   case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                       player.setAngleLeft(false);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                       player.setAngleRight(false);

                   case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                       player.setAcc(false);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                       player.setDec(false);
                       break;
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
           {
               switch(e.getKeyCode())
               {
                   case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                       player.setAngleLeft(true);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                       player.setAngleRight(true);
                       break;

                   case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                       player.setAcc(true);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                   case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                       if(player.getMovingDistance()>0)
                       {
                           player.setDec(true);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           player.setDec(false);
                           player.setMovingDistance(-1);
                       }
                       break;

                   case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:                            
                       if(isGameOver()||isRoundWin())
                       {
                           fenster.dispose();
                       }
                       if(t.isRunning())
                       {
                           pauseGame();
                       }
                       else if(!isGameOver())
                       {
                           resumeGame();
                       }
                       break;

                   case KeyEvent.VK_E:
                       endGame();
                       break;

                   case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                       if(isGameOver())
                       {
                           restartGame();
                       }
                       else if(isRoundWin())
                       {
                           continueGame();
                       }
                       break;

                   case KeyEvent.VK_1:
                       changeDiff(1);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_2:
                       changeDiff(2);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_3:
                       changeDiff(3);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_4:
                       changeDiff(4);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_5:
                       changeDiff(5);
                       break;
                   case KeyEvent.VK_6:
                       changeDiff(6);
                       break;
               }
           }
       });

       t=new Timer(20, new ActionListener()    //timer to control the ticks
       {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               doOnTick();
           }
       });
   }

   public void changeDiff(int schwer)
   {
       Object[] restart={"OK","No"};   //game has to be restarted to change    the difficulty
       int chosenRestart=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(fenster,"In order to change the difficulty, the game has to be restarted.\nDo you really want to change the difficulty?","Warning!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,restart,restart[0]);
       if(chosenRestart==0)    //if yes is chosen, the difficulty will change and the game restarts
       {
           this.schwer=schwer;
           restartGame();
       }
   }

   private void createGameObjects()
   {
       if(player==null)    //if there is no player, there will be a new one
       {
           player=new Player(new Coordinate(900,150),20,Math.toRadians(180),5);
       }

       if(goal==null)  //if there is no goal, there will be a new one
       {
           goal=new Goal(new Coordinate(prefSize.width-200,100),80,80);
       }

       initPlayer();   //player is initialized
       initSpawns();   //spawns are initialized
       obstacles=new Obstacle[schwer];
       initObstacles();    //objects are initialized
   }

   private void initPlayer()   //player is initialized
   {
       player.setObjectPosition(new Coordinate(40,700));
       player.setMovingAngle(Math.toRadians(-90));
   }

   public void initObstacles() //objects are initialized
   {
       for(int i=0;i<obstacles.length;i++)
       {
           obstacles[i]=new Obstacle(new Coordinate(90,150),70,70,5);
           obstacles[i].setMovingDistance(schwer*2+c);
           obstacleSpawn(i);
       }
   }

   public void obstacleSpawn(int i)    //objects spawn at a random spawn
   {
       double zufall=Math.random();
       if(zufall<=0.33)
       {
           obstacles[i].spawn(cSpawn0);
       }
       else if(zufall<=0.67)
       {
           obstacles[i].spawn(cSpawn1);
       }
       else
       {
           obstacles[i].spawn(cSpawn2);
       }
   }

   public void initSpawns()    //spawns are initialized
   {
       cSpawn0=new Coordinate((Math.random()*prefSize.width-200)+100,(Math.random()*prefSize.height-200)+100);
       cSpawn1=new Coordinate((Math.random()*prefSize.width-200)+100,(Math.random()*prefSize.height-200)+100);
       cSpawn2=new Coordinate((Math.random()*prefSize.width-200)+100,(Math.random()*prefSize.height-200)+100);

       spawn0=new Spawn();
       spawn1=new Spawn();
       spawn2=new Spawn();
   }

   private void startGame()    //timer starts
   {
       t.start();
   }

   public void pauseGame() //timer stops
   {
       t.stop();
   }

   public void resumeGame()    //if game is not over, timer starts again
   {
       if(!isGameOver())
       {
           t.start();
       }
   }

   public void continueGame()  //if the current round is won, a new one will start
   {
       if(isRoundWin())
       {
           setRoundWin(false);
           player.setMovingDistance(5);
           createGameObjects();
           startGame();
       }
   }

   public void restartGame()   //if a round is lost, a new game will start
   {
       setGameOver(false);
       setRoundWin(false);
       c=0;
       p=0;
       player.setMovingDistance(5);
       createGameObjects();
       startGame();
   }

   private void endGame()  //game is set to be over
   {
       setGameOver(true);
       pauseGame();
   }

   private void doOnTick() //every tick (controlled by the timer), this will happen:
   {
       if(player.getObjectPosition().getX()   <=0||player.getObjectPosition().getX()>=prefSize.width||player.getObjectPosition().getY()<=0||player.getObjectPosition().getY()>=prefSize.height)
       {
           endGame();
       }
       //if a player leaves the window, the game is over

       for(int i=0;i<schwer;i++)
       {
           if(obstacles[i].getObjectPosition().getX()   <=0||obstacles[i].getObjectPosition().getX()>=prefSize.width||obstacles[i].getObjectPosition().getY()<=0||obstacles[i].getObjectPosition().getY()>=prefSize.height)
           {
               obstacleSpawn(i);
           }
           //if an obstacle leaves the window, it will respawn

           if(player.touches(obstacles[i])||obstacles[i].touches(player))
           {
               endGame();
           }
           //if the player touches an obstacle, the game is over
       }

       if(player.touches(goal)||goal.touches(player))
       {
           setRoundWin(true);
           pauseGame();
           c=c+1;
           p=(int)(p+(player.getMovingDistance()*schwer));
       }
       //if the player touches the goal, the round is won and the new scores    for round and points are
       //calculated

       player.makeMove();  //the player is moved

       for(int i=0;i<schwer;i++)
       {
           obstacles[i].makeMove();
       }
       //all obstacles are moved

       repaint();  //the game is repainted
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
       super.paintComponent(g);    //everything of the original    paintComponent is done
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    //g2d is g
       g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
       //antialiasing is turned on -> Kantenglättung
       setBackground(Color.GRAY);  //background is gray

       player.paintMe(g);  //player is painted

       for(int i=0;i<schwer;i++)
       {
           obstacles[i].paintMe(g);
       }
       //all obstacles are painted

       spawn0.paintMe(g,cSpawn0);
       spawn1.paintMe(g,cSpawn1);
       spawn2.paintMe(g,cSpawn2);
       //all spawns are painted

       goal.paintMe(g);    //goal is painted

       g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.BOLD,30));
       g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       g.drawString("Rounds: "+c,prefSize.width-200,30);
       g.setColor(Color.RED);
       g.drawString("Points: "+p,30,30);
       //rounds and points GUI are painted

       if(isGameOver())
       {
           for(int i=0;i<max.length;i++)
           {
               if(p>=max[i][0])
               {
                   for(int j=max.length-1;j>i+1;j--)
                   {
                       max[j][0]=max[j-1][0];
                       max[j][1]=max[j-1][1];
                       max[j][2]=max[j-1][2];
                   }
                   max[i][0]=p;
                   max[i][1]=c;
                   max[i][2]=schwer;
                   break;
               }
           }
           //if the game is lost, all highscores are sized

           g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.BOLD,50));
           g.setColor(Color.RED);
           g.drawString("GAME OVER!",prefSize.width/2-170,prefSize.height/5);
                                       //the "GAME OVER!" is painted on the screen ...
           g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.BOLD,20));
           g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
           g.drawString("Highscores",prefSize.width/2-100,prefSize.height/4);
           for(int i=0;i<max.length;i++)
           {
               g.drawString(max[i][0]+" Points",200,300+30*i);
               g.drawString(max[i][1]+" Rounds",500,300+30*i);
               g.drawString(schwerMax(max[i][2]),700,300+30*i);
           }
                                               //... and all the highscores
       }
       if(isRoundWin())
       {
           g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.BOLD,50));
           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
           g.drawString("ROUND WON!",prefSize.width/2-130,prefSize.height/5);
       }   //if the round is won, this is painted on the screen
   }
   }
   ```
2. The abstract Class GameObject (Player, Obstacle and Goal are game objects; I tried something different for the spawns already):

   ```
   public abstract class GameObject
   {
   private Coordinate objectPosition;
   private double width;
   private double height;
   private double movingAngle;
   private double movingDistance;

   public GameObject(Coordinate objectPosition,double width,double height)
   {
       this.objectPosition=objectPosition;
       this.width=width;
       this.height=height;

       movingAngle=0;
       movingDistance=0;
   }

   public Coordinate getObjectPosition()
   {
       return objectPosition;
   }

   public void setObjectPosition(Coordinate objectPosition)
   {
       this.objectPosition=objectPosition;
   }

   public double getWidth()
   {
       return width;
   }

   public void setWidth(double width)
   {
       this.width=width;
   }

   public double getHeight()
   {
       return height;
   }

   public void setHeight(double height)
   {
       this.height=height;
   }

   public double getMovingAngle()
   {
       return movingAngle;
   }

   public void setMovingAngle(double movingAngle)
   {
       this.movingAngle=movingAngle;
   }

   public double getMovingDistance()
   {
       return movingDistance;
   }

   public void setMovingDistance(double movingDistance)
   {
       this.movingDistance=movingDistance;
   }

   public boolean isLeftOf(GameObject that)
   {
       return this.getObjectPosition().getX()+this.getWidth()<that.getObjectPosition().getX();
   }

   public boolean isAbove(GameObject that)
   {
       return this.getObjectPosition().getY()+this.getHeight()<that.getObjectPosition().getY();
   }

   public boolean touches(GameObject that)
   {
       if(this.isLeftOf(that)) return false;
       if(that.isLeftOf(this)) return false;
       if(this.isAbove(that)) return false;
       if(that.isAbove(this)) return false;

       return true;
   }

   public static Coordinate polarToCartesianCoordinates(double angle)
   {
       double x=Math.cos(angle);
       double y=Math.sin(angle);

       return new Coordinate(x,y);
   }

   public void moveGameObject()
   {
       Coordinate direction=polarToCartesianCoordinates(movingAngle);
       objectPosition.setX(objectPosition.getX()+direction.getX()*movingDistance);
       objectPosition.setY(objectPosition.getY()+direction.getY()*movingDistance);
   }

   public void makeMove()
   {
       moveGameObject();
   }

   protected abstract void paintMe(Graphics g);
   }
   ```
3. The Obstacle:

   ```
   public class Obstacle extends GameObject
   {
   private Shape transformedObstacle=new RoundRectangle2D.Double();

   public Obstacle(Coordinate position,double size,double MovingAngle,double MovingDistance)
   {
       super(position,size,size/3);

       this.setMovingAngle(MovingAngle);
       this.setMovingDistance(MovingDistance);
   }

   public Shape getTransformedObstacle()
   {
       return transformedObstacle;
   }

   public void setTransformedObstacle(Shape transformedObstacle)
   {
       this.transformedObstacle=transformedObstacle;
   }

   public void spawn(Coordinate spawn)
   {
       this.setObjectPosition(spawn);
       this.setMovingAngle(Math.toRadians(Math.random()*360));
   }

   public void paintMe(java.awt.Graphics g)
   {
       Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
       this.paintComponent(g2d);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g2d)
   {
       RoundRectangle2D quader=new RoundRectangle2D.Double(this.getObjectPosition().getX(),this.getObjectPosition().getY(),this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),5,5);
       g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);

       AffineTransform transform=new AffineTransform();
       transform.rotate(this.getMovingAngle(),quader.getCenterX(),quader.getCenterY());
       Shape transformed=transform.createTransformedShape(quader);
       g2d.fill(transformed);

       setTransformedObstacle(transformed);
   }
   }
   ```
4. The Spawn:

   ```
   public class Spawn
   {
   public void paintMe(java.awt.Graphics g,Coordinate position)
   {
       Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
       paintSpawn(g2d,position);
   }

   public void paintSpawn(Graphics2D g2d,Coordinate position)
   {
       RoundRectangle2D spawn=new RoundRectangle2D.Double(position.getX(),position.getY(),50,50,100,100);
       g2d.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);

       g2d.fill(spawn);
   }
   }
   ```

Here is a video of the gouped obstacles and moving spawns: https://youtu.be/N8Rq3yKblXk

I know, this is a lot of code, but I hope, somebody can help me find the problem.

.

Cheers

Lindwurm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the reference of `spawn0` (`Coordinate`) to `Obstacle`, this then updated when the `Obstacle` moves, so now `Obstacle` and `spawn0` have the same location and thus, move along with each other.

`Spawn` should be constructed with it's own location (this should not be then shared), `Spawn` should then become responsible for the life cycle of the `Obstacle` and spawn new `Obstacle` as required (and remove old ones)

Comment: Ok, I see. I added own `Coordinate`s for the `Spawn`s and completely removed the `Coordinate`s `cSpawn0`, `cSpawn1` and `cSpawn2`. I also remove the old `Obstacle`s now and spawn the new ones.  But still the `Spawn`s move with the obstacles. I do not even have implemented a `setPosition` method or something equal in the `Spawn` class, just a `getPosition` for spawning the next `Obstacle`.

Comment: Aha, I changed the part when the `Obstacle` spawns. It now gets a new `Coordinate` with the same x and y as the `Coordinate` of the `Spawn`, so it does not change the coordinate of the `Spawn`.